# Write to a file in python as synchronized

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm using thread in python as the following:

```
ls = ...# a list
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
    for e in ls:
        th = classB(e)
        executor.submit(th)
```

so, each `classB` compute a list of string. I need to write this computed list to a file. So how can access the file without error as all the thread will write to this file.

From my side I did:

```
while not queue.empty():
    ls = q.get()
    file_object  = open(self.fileName,  "w")
    for p in ls:
      file_object.write(path + "\n")
      file_object.close()
      q.task_done()
```

and in the `classB` when I compute the list I did:

```
q.put(self.finalList)
```

The problem is I have only one result in my file

How can I do that more correct?